# Slide up/down effect in jquery resizes image - how to avoid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When applying the slide up/down effect in jquery , the image is resized as much the menu slides up/down, but i want the slide effect with the image going down/up, not resizing.

How to slide the image purely?

Thanks

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 $('.logo').hide(); 
});

$(document).ready(function () {  
  $(window).scroll(function (event) {
    // what the y position of the scroll is
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

    // whether that's below the form
    if (y >= 30) {
      // if so, ad the fixed class
      $('.menu').addClass('fixed');
   $('.menu').slideDown();   
   $('.logo').slideDown();   
    } else {
      // otherwise remove it
      //$('.logo2').removeClass('fixed'); 
   $('.menu').slideUp();   
   $('.logo').slideUp();   
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.menu.fixed {
 position:fixed;
 background:#000;
 width:100%;
 height: 100px;
 z-index:100;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}

.logo {
 margin-left:50%; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
<img src="http://www.digifloor.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/google-logo.png" height="80px" class="logo" />
</div>

dadadasdassdasdadasdasasdasd <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
dadadasdassdasdadasdasasdasd <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
dadadasdassdasdadasdasasdasd <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
dadadasdassdasdadasdasasdasd <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
dadadasdassdasdadasdasasdasd <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
dadadasdassdasdadasdasasdasd <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
dadadasdassdasdadasdasasdasd <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
dadadasdassdasdadasdasasdasd <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
dadadasdassdasdadasdasasdasd <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
dadadasdassdasdadasdasasdasd <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
dadadasdassdasdadasdasasdasd <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
dadadasdassdasdadasdasasdasd <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1j24z3va/

Comment: No, the image should be hidden on load and slides when scrolling page

Answer (score 2):

slideUp() / slideDown() won't help you should use [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function(event) {
    // what the y position of the scroll is
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

    // whether that's below the form
    if (y >= 30) {
      // if so, ad the fixed class
      $('.menu').stop().animate({
        top: '0'
      }, 500);
    } else {
      // otherwise remove it
      $('.menu').stop().animate({
        top: '-100px'
      }, 500);

    }
  });
});
```

```css
.menu {
  position: fixed;
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  top: -100px;
}
.logo {
  margin-left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <img src="http://www.digifloor.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/google-logo.png" height="80px" class="logo" />
</div>

dadadasdassdasdadasdasasdasd
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />dadadasdassdasdadasdasasdasd
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />dadadasdassdasdadasdasasdasd
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />dadadasdassdasdadasdasasdasd
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />dadadasdassdasdadasdasasdasd
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />dadadasdassdasdadasdasasdasd
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />dadadasdassdasdadasdasasdasd
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />dadadasdassdasdadasdasasdasd
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />dadadasdassdasdadasdasasdasd
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />dadadasdassdasdadasdasasdasd
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />dadadasdassdasdadasdasasdasd
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />dadadasdassdasdadasdasasdasd
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
```

Comment: Hi just checked on IE and this code do not work. Any workaround for IE?